# Does Postgresql plpgsql/sql support short circuiting in the where clause?

Tags: sql, postgresql, plpgsql

If I have the following toy query

```
SELECT *
FROM my_tables
WHERE my_id in (
    SELECT my_other_id
    FROM my_other_tables
) AND some_slow_func(arg) BETWEEN 1 AND 2;
```

Would the first condition in the WHERE clause short circuit the second condition which would have a complex run time?

I'm working on some sql that is actually part of a FOR LOOP in plpgsql, and I could do iterations over all records that exist in the my_other_tables, and then test within the scope of the FOR LOOP with the some_slow_func(). But I'm curious if sql supports, or plpgsql supports short circuiting.

Some Research:
I looked in the Postgres mailing lists and found this saying SQL in general doesn't support short circuiting:

http://www.postgresql.org/message-id/171423D4-9229-4D56-B06B-58D29BB50A77@yahoo.com

But one of the responses says that order can be enforced through subselects. I'm not exactly sure what he's speaking about. I know what a subselect is, but I'm not sure how order would be enforced? Could some one clarify this for me?

Comment: I don't think that short-circuiting is relevant; SQL is supposed to be set-oriented, and the result should not depend on the order of evaluation. An exeption to this *might* be a UNION of two subqueries, both with a LIMIT plus an additional LIMIT on the query as a whole. But LIMIT is borderline anyway... Side-effects of evaluation should not be possible in a truly relational RSBMS (maybe except for LATERAL). In short: order of evaluation only affects performance, and not (the correctness of) the results, IMHO. That's why we should leave the order of evaluation to the planner.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

As documented, the evaluation order in a WHERE clause is supposed to be unpredictable.

It's different with subqueries. With PostgreSQL older than version 12, the simplest and common technique to drive the evaluation order is to write a subquery in a CTE. To make sure that the `IN(...)` is evaluated first, your code could be written as:

```
WITH subquery AS
(select * from my_tables
  WHERE my_id in (SELECT my_other_id FROM my_other_tables)
)
SELECT * FROM subquery
  WHERE some_slow_func(arg) BETWEEN 1 AND 2;
```

Starting with PostgreSQL version 12, `WITH` subqueries may be inlined by the optimizer (see the [doc page on WITH queries](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/queries-with.html) for all the details), and the non-inlining is only guaranteed when adding the `MATERIALIZED` clause:

```
WITH subquery AS MATERIALIZED
(select * ... the rest is similar as above)
```

---

Something else that you may tweak is the cost of your function to signal to the optimizer that it's slow. The default cost for a function is `100`, and it can be altered with a statement like:

```
ALTER FUNCTION funcname(argument types) cost N;
```

where `N` is the estimated per-call cost, expressed in an arbitrary unit that should be compared to the [Planner Cost Constants](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/runtime-config-query.html#RUNTIME-CONFIG-QUERY-CONSTANTS).

Comment: Yes, using WITH would be a good quick way to limit the set. Not sure why I didn't think of this.... I love using WITH. Also, didn't even think about changing the cost of the planner. I knew about it but I've always let postgres take care of optimization. I've actually never used it before, but will read more into it. Thank you for bringing it to my attention!

Comment: You can also include `COST N` when you define the function, of course.

Comment: Note that this answer is no longer correct in v12 and later. In v12, `WITH` elements are no longer materialized if they are referenced just once, as in the example. This means that the query in the `WITH` element is basically inlined into the main query. From there on, the order of execution of the `WHERE` predicates is not deterministic. However, you can add the `MATERIALIZED` directive to force materialization of the `WITH` element. See https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-with.html for more information.

Comment: @pbillen: thanks for the heads-up, the answer is now updated.

Answer (score 5):

I know this is an old question, but recently ran into similar issue, and found using a CASE predicate in the WHERE clause worked better for me.  In the context of the answer above:

```
SELECT *
  FROM my_tables
 WHERE CASE WHEN my_id in (SELECT my_other_id
                             FROM my_other_tables)
           AND some_slow_func(arg) BETWEEN 1 AND 2
           THEN 1 
           ELSE 0 
      END = 1;
```

This makes for SQL that is slightly more DB agnostic.  Of course, it may not make use of indexes if you have some on my_id, but depending on the context you're in, this could be a good option.

Comment: +1 this technique is actually [mentioned in the docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-expressions.html#SYNTAX-EXPRESS-EVAL) along with its limitations.

Answer (score 2):

According to [the Postgresql docs](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/sql-expressions.html#SYNTAX-EXPRESS-EVAL) and [this answer by Tom Lane](http://www.postgresql.org/message-id/454.1304184576@sss.pgh.pa.us), the order of execution of WHERE constraints is not reliable.

I think your best bet here may be to add that other part of your WHERE clause into the top of your function and "fail fast"; ie, run `my_id in (
    SELECT my_other_id
    FROM my_other_tables)` in your function, and if it doesn't pass, return right there before doing you intensive processing.  That should get you about the same effect.

Comment: Thanks for the references. I've been looking at the postgresql documentation all day, and I didn't come across that explanation. I appreciate your quick response.

Comment: No problem. One tip - when you're looking at those forums, at the bottom there are usually sections for "In Response To" and "Responses". If you follow links under responses, you'll probably get more information.  In this case, all I did was follow the response by Tom Lane on the post you linked in the OP.