# PostgresSQL AND Operator

Tags: postgresql, optimization

I have a query like the following.

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE A AND B
```

Where A and B are conditions (B is slower than A).

Does anybody know if A and B will be evaluated all the time or if B is only evaluated if A evaluates to 'true'?

Many thanks

Patrick

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Does Postgresql plpgsql/sql support short circuiting in the where clause?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14943475/does-postgresql-plpgsql-sql-support-short-circuiting-in-the-where-clause)

Comment: PostgreSQL does do short-circuit, so if first is false the others aren’t evaluated. *However* the order is not defined. PostgreSQL may evaluate A first, or B first, if it thinks one is “better” to do first.

Comment: See [4.2.14. Expression Evaluation Rules](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-expressions.html#SYNTAX-EXPRESS-EVAL).

Answer (score 0):

The behaviour, which you desribe is called ["Short circuit evaluation"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation).

There are already many entries regarding this topic on stackOverflow, e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5195094/sql-server-predicates-lazy).
But in short:
You do not know!
See PostgreSQL documentation [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/sql-expressions.html#SYNTAX-EXPRESS-EVAL).
It says:

> The order of evaluation of subexpressions is not defined. In particular, the inputs of an operator or function are not necessarily evaluated left-to-right or in any other fixed order. Furthermore, if the result of an expression can be determined by evaluating only some parts of it, then other subexpressions **might** not be evaluated at all.

If you continue reading the documentation then you see that it stays consistently vague like this.

So **summary**: In general SQL is declarative, meaning that you can tell the database-framework what you want, but not how you want it to be computed.
The system can make freely choices in that regard.